# What is difference between python --version and conda list in activated environment?

Tags: python, conda

I activated my environment and run this two code but results are different. How can I use right python version I want?

(1)

```
python --version
Python 3.9.6
```

(2)

```
conda list '^python$'
Name Version Build Channel
Python 3.8.18  hb885b13_0 defaults
```

Comment: How can I use right python version I want?" - well, if you use the `python` command, you get the version of Python that `python --version` lists, and similarly for Conda. Is this unexpected? "I activated my environment" - **what** environment? A Conda environment? A Python virtual environment (created with `venv`)? Something else?

Comment: @Karl I think it's safe to assume it's a Conda environment since they're using `conda`. So what's unexpected is that the `python` command doesn't match the environment. But you're not wrong to ask cause at worst, `conda` could be the script, which would show the base env info even if the env isn't active. I didn't consider that when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @wjandrea unfortunately I don't really know anything about Conda except that it exists. I would hope there is a relevant canonical for this sort of issue, though.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, those should match. But I bet your Python 3.9.6 is not in your conda environment. Try running `python` and checking [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable). Here's what I get normally:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python3'
```

And after activating one of my environments:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/wja/Programs/miniconda3/envs/anaconda3_11/bin/python3'
```

The problem could be that you have a shell alias called `python`. If you're using Bash for instance, check like this:

```bash
$ alias python
alias python='python3'
```

(This explains the `sys.executable` output I got above by the way: I set it up like that in my `~/.bashrc`.)

As a workaround until you fix the problem, you can use `conda run`:

```bash
conda run --no-capture-output python
```

Or, in Bash, you can use a backslash to bypasses aliases. In my case, without the environment active, it bypasses the Python 3 alias:

```bash
$ \python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
```

Comment: Another possibility is that a Conda env isn't actually active, but that would seem to contradict the question. See [my comment](/q/77108991/#comment135934505_77108991). I'll edit this in if it proves to be the case.

Comment: The environment not being activated is the most likely explanation in my experience.

Comment: Thank you! I had alias in ~/.zshrc so I removed and solved.